# Cannot install snappy with brew - fatal error: 'cassert' file not found

Tags: ffmpeg, homebrew, snappy

I am on an old mac - 10.14.6 - and I am trying to install ffmpeg via brew.

I am finding errors during the make of snappy

When I try to `brew install snappy` the same errors persist:

```
==> Installing dependencies for snzip: snappy
==> Installing snzip dependency: snappy
==> Patching
==> cmake . -DSNAPPY_BUILD_TESTS=OFF -DSNAPPY_BUILD_BENCHMARKS=OFF
==> make install
Last 15 lines from /Users/<home>/Library/Logs/Homebrew/snappy/02.make:
In file included from /tmp/snappy-20240323-80108-r3czy0/snappy-1.1.10/snappy.cc:29:
In file included from /tmp/snappy-20240323-80108-r3czy0/snappy-1.1.10/snappy-internal.h:34:
/tmp/snappy-20240323-80108-r3czy0/snappy-1.1.10/snappy-stubs-internal.h:40:10: fatal error: 'cassert' file not found
40 | #include <cassert>
  |          ^~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/snappy.dir/snappy-sinksource.cc.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/snappy.dir/snappy-c.cc.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/snappy.dir/snappy-stubs-internal.cc.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/snappy.dir/snappy.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/snappy.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has as old of a mac as I do and cannot install ffmpeg via brew, then the work around that I found was to download and extract the zip of ffmpeg and place it in the same directory/folder as the file that I wanted to run the command line:

[Download ffmpeg zip](https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/)

Once I downloaded and extracted the zip, I moved ffmpeg in the same directory, followed by running the following command:

```
./ffmpeg -i Not-if.mov -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 -c:a copy not-if-hevc.mp4
```

This is a one hour, twenty seven minutes, thirty two second and one frame file, so it will take a while for it to complete the task for me to verify if it worked, but for now, it is displaying stats in the terminal with every frame processed, so I believe it is working.

BTW, I have spent most of the day trying to get this going and I just finished a graveyard shift and I am working a graveyard shift tonight. I really should be sleeping right now. I went away from software development to get away from such a sleep deprived lifestyle, but if the notification on the screen shows "HDR" when the UHD dvd is playing, then this will have been so worth it.